# Did I create this array of strings properly? c++

Tags: c++, arrays

The directions were to "Create a function that creates an array of 50,000 strings - repeat "Hi", "Hey", "Hello", "What's up" 12,500 times. Return the array of strings from the function. Give the function an appropriate name and return type."

This was the code that I made, it compiles and all but Im not sure if the numbers are correct.

```
string* greetingArray()
{
    string greetings[50000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
    {
        greetings[i++] = "Hi";
        greetings[i++] = "Hey";
        greetings[i++] = "Hello";
        greetings[i++] = "What's up";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
    {
        cout << greetings[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    greetingArray();
    return 0;
}
```

I called it in a simple main, Is this an okay way to call the function?
I had the code in the first for loop as "i < 12500", im just not sure though.

Comment: either remove the i++ on the for loop, or remove the i++ in the last greetings[i++], you are actually skipping one string every time through the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, when you are saying

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
{
    greetings[i++] = "Hi";
    greetings[i++] = "Hey";
    greetings[i++] = "Hello";
    greetings[i++] = "What's up";
}
```

You are incorrectly incrementing `i` after each for-loop, so every 5th index in your array is uninitialized.

Here's a run through:

- i = 0, greetings[0] = "Hi", i++ evaluates to 1
- i = 1, greetings[1] = "Hey", i++ evaluates to 2
- i = 2, greetings[2] = "Hello", i++ evaluates to 3
- i = 3, greetings[3] = "What's up", i++ evaluates to 4
- i = 4, end of for loop, i++ evaluates to 5
- i = 5, greetings[5] = "Hi"

At this point `greetings[4]` is uninitialized, so accessing it is undefined.

You *could* change your code to be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
{
    greetings[i++] = "Hi";
    greetings[i++] = "Hey";
    greetings[i++] = "Hello";
    greetings[i] = "What's up";
}
```

But this is not a very safe way to do things. We get lucky because 50k is divisble by 4.

**EDIT**

For posterity, I guess I should point you towards the other answers that mention you need to actually return the array from the function instead of `0`. So `return greetings;` at the end.

A better solution would be to use a `std::vector`:

```
#define AMOUNT 50000 //change this number for whatever count of strings you need
std::vector<std::string> greetings;
while(greetings.size() < AMOUNT){
   greetings.push_back("Hi");
   greetings.push_back("Hey");
   greetings.push_back("Hello");
   greetings.push_back("What's up");
}

//print the vector's contents
for (std::vector<string>::iterator strIter = greetings.begin(); strIter != greetings.end(); ++strIter){
   cout << *strIter << endl;
}
```

Comment: Never mind, I didn't see the last line of your answer

Comment: Also some write up for return value would be nice

Comment: yeah, I missed you last line of your comment.  looks good to me

Comment: Awesome, but is each greeting going to print 50000 times or 12500 times each. Each one needs to print 12500 times to make the total 50000.

Comment: @Christoph: They'll each print 1/4 * 50000 times = 12500 times each. So, yes.

Comment: @AndyG actually the next part of the program is to use vectors, so my question to you regarding that vector code is, how do you print to the screen the greeting messages, I am not sure if that already does.

Comment: @Christoph: Edited the post to print the vector using an `iterator`. Be sure to read up on those!

Comment: Great! Your answer includes more info on everything in it, but everyone else's work just as well, thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @Christoph: So upvote them! If their answers are helpful, why not?

Comment: @AndyG I would if I had enough reputation. For now I can only choose an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The function is wrong. You declared its return type as

```
string*
```

however the function always return zero (or null) pointer. That is the function does not return the array and it may not return the array because it is defined as a local variable

```
string greetings[50000];
```

that will be destroyed after exiting the function

This loop is also invalid

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
{
    greetings[i++] = "Hi";
    greetings[i++] = "Hey";
    greetings[i++] = "Hello";
    greetings[i++] = "What's up";
}
```

For example the element of the array with index 4 will not be set.

More correctly the function could be defined the following way (without testing)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string * greetingArray( size_t n )
{
    const size_t N = 4;
    const char *words[N] = { "Hi", "Hey", "Hello", "What's up" };

    std::string *greetings = new std::string[n];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        greetings[i] = words[i % N];
    }

    return greetings;
}


int main()
{
    size_t N = 50000;

    std::string *greetings = greetingArray( N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << greetings[i] << std::endl;
    }

    delete [] greetings;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you delete the greetings array at the end?

Comment: @Christoph To free the allocated memory.

Comment: @Christoph: Because Vlad from Moscow used a dynamically generated array (see the `new` keyword), which allocates memory on the heap, not the stack. When you do this **you** are responsible for managing the memory now, and thus need to call `delete []`

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure, why don't you **test** your code? It doesn't do what it should. Lets first read the assigment:

> Create a function that creates an array of 50,000 strings - repeat "Hi", "Hey", "Hello", "What's up" 12,500 times. Return the array of strings from the function. Give the function an appropriate name and return type.

Lets start from defining the function - it has to have an appriopriate name and return type. It has to return an **array of strings**. In C++ it will be declared as:

```
string* yourFunctionName();
```

so that part is correct. Next:

> Create a function that creates an array of 50,000 strings

```
{
   string myArray[50000];
```

Next:

> repeat "Hi", "Hey", "Hello", "What's up" 12,500 times

```
   for(unsigned int i=0;i<12500;){
      myArray[i*4]="Hi";
      myArray[i*4+1]="Hey";
      myArray[i*4+2]="Hello";
      myArray[i*4+3]=What's up";
   }
```

You have to do "*4" because you repeat **4** things, thru the whole array (note: 12500*4=50000). Last thing, which you actually **didn't** do:

> Return the array of strings from the function

You, in your code, return "0". 0 ain't an array of strings. Do it like this:

```
   return myArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works quite well for me

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

const unsigned arraySize = 50000;

std::array<std::string, arraySize> greetingArray()
{
    std::array<std::string, arraySize> greetings;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i != greetings.size(); i += 4)
    {
        greetings[i] = "Hi";
        greetings[i+1] = "Hey";
        greetings[i+2] = "Hello";
        greetings[i+3] = "What's up";
    }

    return greetings;  // return the array, not 0 !
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::string, arraySize>  greetings = greetingArray();
    for(unsigned i = 0; i != 20; ++i) std::cout << greetings.at(i) << '\n'; // 20 outputs is plenty to check if it worked
    return 0;
}
```